# Item undefined in Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

```
- name: Web Security group
  ec2_group:
    name: "{{ vpc_name }}-web-db-sg"
    state: present
    description: Security group for RDS servers in the VPC
    vpc_id: "{{vpc_id}}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    rules:
      - proto: tcp
        group_id: "{{ item }}"
        ports:
          - 5432
          - 3306
          - 1433

    with_items: "{{public_sg_ids}}"
  register: web_sg
```

This is the snippet of code which i am trying to run, but couldnt. My goal is to make three rules for AWS security group where public_sg_ids is the list of security group ids of three public security groups ['sg-03198a28b7edf1f0e', 'sg-038b16577691b2d2f', 'sg-047fe11a7290946b5'].
The error is

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation:

```
- name: Web Security group
  ec2_group:
    name: "{{ vpc_name }}-web-db-sg"
    state: present
    description: Security group for RDS servers in the VPC
    vpc_id: "{{vpc_id}}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    rules:
      - proto: tcp
        group_id: "{{ item }}"
        ports:
          - 5432
          - 3306
          - 1433

  with_items: "{{public_sg_ids}}"
  register: web_sg
```

For more examples about `Loops` see [Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html?highlight=loops#standard-loops)

Comment: I did, but then if i follow what you have written , It only creates one security group instead of three. With the ports open 5432, 3306 and 1433 for the last element of public_sg_ids.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ‘loop’ instead of ‘with_items’